# UITableView: Check rows in edit mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, checkbox

I'm new to iPhone SDK 3.0.

I've seen table view edit mode where you can check multiple row items and then delete them or move them.

The picture here (http://twitpic.com/khmog) illustrates what I mean. I've also seen this in several other apps, such as "Groceries".

Could anyone tell me how to do this? Can this be done using 3.0 APIs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution here:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/table-view-multi-row-edit-mode.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Apple uploaded "TableMultiSelect" as sample codes on iOS Developer Program since 2011-10-12.

It explains only multiple deletion, but I suppose you can change it for moving.

Though it can be used only from iOS5..
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score -1):

There was a demonstration of this on the CS193P course (available on iTunes U). I'm pretty sure it was the Loren Britcher session.